# atom.io Laravel autoprediction woes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, atom-editor

I'm trying to get PHP to autocomplete for my Laravel project - I've been trying lots of different packages, but none seem to work...

Here's a screenshot from a PHP class:

[image]

I need `$table->` to autocomplete and suggest all the functions available to it! (functions such as `->string(...)`, `->text(...)`, `->timestamps()`, etc.)

Can anyone suggest anything?

I have the following **php-related** packages installed:

- **autocomplete-php** (this seems to only work for standard PHP functions?)
- **php-twig** (TWIG related only...)
- **language-php** (basic PHP syntax...)

But I need something more. I need to be able to identify all the classes in my Laravel project and auto-suggest their functions!

Comment: Wich IDE are you working with ? If something like PHPStorm you need a file called _ide_helpers.php in your root directory.

Comment: @ChainList The editor is [Atom](http://atom.io), it's present in the title of the question as well as the question tags.

Comment: OK did not see, i'm sorry. Like @Bogdan said, you can use Atom Ctags.

Comment: did you get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CTags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) to index the definitions. Have a look at this Atom package:

> [Atom Ctags](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ctags)

Don't worry that the animated demo there is presented for C, it should work with PHP just as well.

Comment: This is just what I need. Thanks! But how do I get it to work? I installed it, but when I type $table-> none of the functions are coming up?

Comment: This is just awesome, thanks!

Bogdan, to enable this you need to disable "autocomplete-php", actually just leave "atom-ctags" and "autocomplete-plus" (this one is needed).

Comment: After some time I've decided to give atom-autocomplete-php package second chance. Right now it works awesome together with atom-ctags.

For example while typing, autocomplete searches primary using atom-autocomplete-php, ctags aren't showing me unnecessary methods I wouldn't use.

But if I don't have any results, ctags are back in action. For example with ctags disabled I wouldn't get these results, but when I enable ctags the magic happens: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YuAQC.png

Tested on Atom 1.9.4

Comment: Anyone has, for any chance, successfully had to import use statements while using Ctags? autocomplete-php seems to work half the time for importing use! :\